# how am i going to turn this right way. get data from prompt to console using if statement the right way

Tags: javascript, if-statement, command-prompt, console.log

no matter what I pass in the prompt string or number it's returned as 'welcome to the dashboard' even if I put string instead of a number.

```js
let user = prompt('user name:');
let id = prompt('user id:');

let dev = parseInt(id);


if (typeof user === 'undefined' || dev.length === 0) {
  console.error('you miss one of the inputs.');

} else if (typeof user === 'string' && typeof dev === 'number') {
  console.log('welocme on yto your dashboard.');
} else {
  console.log('either user name or ID  is wrong please check again');
}
```

Comment: Anything returned from prompt() is always a string. `typeof id` will always be a string. Are you trying to check if `id` is a "valid" number?

Comment: yes, you are right I am trying to check if the input was a number or not. so how to solve this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prompt` returns a `String`, which can be trimmed down (removes whitespace before and after). You can then check to see if the strings are of length 0, and check to see whether or not `dev` parsed the value of the `id` correctly:

```js
let user = prompt('Username:').trim();
let id = prompt('User ID:').trim();

let dev = parseInt(id);

if (!(user && id)) {
  console.error('You missed one of the inputs.');
} else if (!isNaN(dev)) {
  console.log('Welcome to your dashboard.');
} else {
  console.error('Either your username or ID is wrong. Please check again.');
}
```